# Unable to display image in html flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to render an image in html in flask, the path is pointing to the correct file but its not rendering some how.

#VIEWS

```
@inventory_bp.route("/show")
def show_image():
    id = 3
    image = Images.query.get(id)
    upload_folder = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
    image_path = os.path.join(upload_folder, image.filename)
    return render_template("image-upload.html",image_url=image_path)
```

#HTML

```
    <div>
      <img src="{{ image_url }}" alt="" />
    </div>
```

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'flaskbp/uploads')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

[image]

Comment: when i am debugging something like this i like to look at the generated html in chrome dev tools (shit + ctrl + j) so if you could update your question with a screen shot of the html when you go to the web page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `image_path` you're creating is the *file path* on your OS (e.g. `C:\path\to\project\flaskbp\uploads\image.png`. This is not the right `src` for the `img` element on your HTML.

Instead, you can place the uploads folder under the `static` folder, and then create the URL of the image dynamically.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/show")
def show_image():
    image_path = "uploads/image.png"
    return render_template("image.html", image_url=image_path)
```

```
<div>
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=image_url) }}"/>
</div>
```

Folder structure:

```
\---root
    |   app.py
    |
    +---static
    |   \---uploads
    |           image.png
    |
    \---templates
            image.html
```